# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' ao abrir arquivo .dbf de 300 mega

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados

Eu tento abrir um arquivo `.dbf` de 300MB em meu código, porém aparece este erro **'$exception.Message' threw an exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'**, um arquivo menor de 300KB é aberto normalmente, eu sei que o arquivo é muito grande, mas também sei que é possível executar arquivos desse tamanho (300MB), segue o código:

Estou usando Windows Form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;

namespace LerDBF
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConsultaPrimaria_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= c:\\; Extended Properties = dBASE IV; User ID=; Password=";
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Arquivos DBF|*.dbf";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Selecione o arquivo DBF";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                oConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();

                oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM " + openFileDialog1.FileName;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
                ArrayList dadosComboBox = new ArrayList();
                foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
                {
                    dadosComboBox.Add(c.ColumnName);
                }
                comboBox1.DataSource = dadosComboBox;
                oConn.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + exc.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnConsultaSecundaria_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= c:\\; Extended Properties = dBASE IV; User ID=; Password=";
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Arquivos DBF|*.dbf";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Selecione o arquivo DBF";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                oConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();

                oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM " + openFileDialog1.FileName;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
                ArrayList dadosComboBox = new ArrayList();
                foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
                {
                    dadosComboBox.Add(c.ColumnName);
                }
                comboBox2.DataSource = dadosComboBox;
                oConn.Close();
                dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + exc.Message);
        }
    }
}


}
```

Eu teria que usar alguma *thread* para executar isso em segundo plano?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

A solução é muito simples. Não carregue o arquivo todo na memória. Quando for dar o `SELECT` coloque uma cláusula `WHERE` para pegar só uma parte do registros do `.dbf` e processe em partes. Provavelmente vai ter que criar um laço para repetir a operação até fazer o que deseja com todos os dados, mas tentar colocá-los todos na memória não vai dar certo. Dependendo do objetivo, terá que desenvolver uma lógica complexa para tratar isto.

Você pode também usar um [`DataView`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) para virtualizar os dados. Não sei se funciona perfeitamente com `.dbf` mas acredito que sim.

Em alguns casos um [`DataReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) poderia ser uma solução.

Comment: Cheguei a pensar nessa solução em dividir em partes, porém eu leio o DBF direto do seu path, será que salvar o dbf no banco local e depois executar direto no banco e não DBF daria certo? Vou testar, caso não conseguir eu vou seguir sua lógica

Comment: A ideia de importar o `dbf` é a que recomendaria.

Comment: EU não sou muito bom em banco de dados, mas um cara do trabalho me deu um toque de passar tudo isso para o banco e fazer um JOIN e MERGE, será que no banco é melhor? Ou continuo fazendo em C#?

Comment: Eu acho que é melhor sim.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione seguinte código no seu App.config:

```
 <configuration>
   <runtime>
     <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
 </configuration>
```